# How to make URL String with linkable when sharing it

Tags: ios, swift, string, uiactivityviewcontroller

When sharing URL String via email WhatsApp other sharable component its url formate is not linkable with underline

```
        let encodedStr = dict!.base64EncodedString()
        let appLink =  "https://companyName.com/account/signupbyinvite?\(encodedStr)"
```

When sharing via email message box the url formate is not clickable and underline below like is not visible.

Answer (score 0):

convert the url string in to url

```
  guard let appUrl = URL(string : appLink) else {return}
```

then share with uiactivitycontroller link will auto clickable once its shared. like this

```
 let activityViewController =  UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [appUrl], applicationActivities: nil)
  activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```